# Configure CRA-generated app to NOT download Workbox from CDN, but a local copy

Tags: create-react-app, workbox

I am looking for a recommendation on configuring my CRA-generated app's generated Workbox `service-worker.js` to fetch the Workbox library from my main app bundle's workbox library, so that the app does not need to depend on Google's CDN. By default, the CRA app loads workbox from the Google CDN.

Specifically, I want the generated line `importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");` inside the generated `serice-worker.js` file to be replaced.

There seem to be no elegant solutions to configuring this, and I would be super appreciative if someone could guide me forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [`create-react-app` v4](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v4.0.0), along with the [`cra-template-pwa`](https://github.com/cra-template/pwa).

That will give you a Workbox-based service worker that is self-contained and does not depend on loading anything from the CDN.

Earlier versions of `c-r-a` unfortunately are not customizable in this regard.